# Exchange data between two Raspberry Pi 4 using USB-A cable

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, usb

I have 2 Raspberry pi 4 and I want to exchange data from the first Raspberry pi 4 to the second one using USB-A cable. How can I do this, anyone tried this?

Comment: Strictly speaking what you are asking is impossible. A USB-A to USB-A cable is NOT SUPPORTED. Why you would WANT to do this is unclear when there are so many ways of exchanging data is unclear.

Comment: you are asking about exchanging data between two Linux computers ... the question is not Raspberry Pi specific ... it belongs at a Linux site ... the only time it would be RPi specific, is if you used GPIO pins to connect the two Raspberry Pis

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a raspberry pi specific question. In any case, it will be much easier to use wired or wireless network for exchanging the data. With wired networks you can either use a router/repeater between the Pis or using cross-over cable with manula IP settings to connect them in a "pear-to-pear manner".

Answer (score 1):

This is an X Y problem.

USB is a master/slave communications protocol, and the Raspberry Pi only supports master not slave as is typical for computers rather than devices, so what you ask is not possible.

Instead, consider using ethernet or wifi to do what you want.  It will be faster anyway.  Computer to computer transfer is what ethernet was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

There are special cables. They have active components.

Examples:

- Usb to serial -- serial to usb.
- Usb to ethernet -- ethernet to usb.

However, the Pi 4 has a perfectly functional Ethernet port that can be used.